# Spanish equivalent of "Snap!" or "Jinx!"

Tags: traducción

I was text-chatting to a Spanish-speaking colleague on MS Teams and we both said almost the same thing at the same time - as a British person, my reaction was to say "Snap!" - it's a tradition to say it when you both say the same thing at the same time. I think it's popular in the UK and Australia and New Zealand, and in the US people say "Jinx!" when this happens. I wondered if there is an equivalent in Spanish?

This page explains the English usage of "Snap" and "Jinx": https://separatedbyacommonlanguage.blogspot.com/2006/10/jinx-and-snap.html

Answer (score 7):

Speaking from Madrid, Spain: This is only normal among children. My kids say "¡Chispas!". We said something completely different when I was a child, but I can't remember now!

Comment: Do they also get muted until somebody else says their names? If not it doesn't apply

Comment: Hmmm... I need t check my sources.

Comment: In the Castillian Spanish version of Frozen this is the word they use in the translation for the "Love is an open door" song. I have heard it used also in another movie, but I can't remember which one.

Comment: @SergioVelasquez the muting rule does not apply to the use of _snap_ in the UK. We just say it and move on.

Answer (score 4):

In Colombia you say : "Enchiclado" and it does have the same rules as the UK tradition.

Comment: ¿Dónde? Nunca lo escuché. ¡Qué curioso! :)

Comment: Lo he escuchado en San Diego también.

Comment: En Colombia? nunca lo he escuchado

Comment: Nunca no lo he escuchado, ¿qué hay de "matamos un diablo" o "diga un color"?

Answer (score 3):

In Málaga, in the South of Spain, back in the 80s, we used "chispita!"

Comment: Also with the same traditional rules as being "jinxed"?

Comment: @SergioVelasquez Yes. You seem annoyed because we are not backing your first comment (now removed) up. I don't know about Colombia or the rest of Spain, that's why I have been so precised about the location.

Comment: @SergioVelasquez I am also from Málaga and I never heard about muting until someone said your name. Just the "chispitas" word and life continues as usual :)

Comment: @Miguel Maybe they don't have explained it to you ever. I've just questioned a younger colleague about it and they have the same word and the same rules in his school here in Málaga.

Comment: In the UK _snap_ does not involve muting. You just say it and move on.

Comment: I'm not annoyed at all @RubioRic, just curious. The whole jinxed thing is new to me :D
I removed my comment because it was not informative

Answer (score 3):

In Colombia we usually say: ¡"Embrujado"!
We used the term "Embrujado" when I was a child, which was in the time of the 2000s onwards, I lived part of my childhood in Cali - Colombia and Ureña - Venezuela, there we also used that term

Comment: There is another Colombian answer, maybe you should indicate in which part of Colombia because they differ.

Comment: The truth is, I never heard the term that is above. We used the term "Embrujado" when I was a child, which was in the time of the 2000s onwards, I lived part of my childhood in Cali - Colombia and Ureña - Venezuela, there we also used that term... But I would not know how to answer why it differs... @RubioRic

Comment: I didn't mean that you have to explain why they differ but that you should edit your answer to specify those locations. I know that in different locations, we use different words, that's why I have tried to be more accurate in my answer pointing my city and not just my country.

Comment: Ok, Fine @RubioRic

Answer (score 2):

In Argentina in the 90s we would say '¡Congelado!'. Same rules as Jinxed, from what I'm reading.

Comment: Or, also in Argentina, we would play to [Guli guli, tres piñas](https://elinformantenews.blogspot.com/2008/03/guli-guli-tres-pias.html). Kinda the same, a _little_ more physical, though

Comment: I remember the 3 piñas thing but I've never heard someone say "congelado"

Answer (score 0):

In Catalonia, north-east of Spain, we said "Bis bis!" back in the 80's-90's.

Comment: Same in the Basque Country in the 2000s.